# Parse Json file on S3 using Json Play using Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, playframework, play-json

I want to access a json file from S3 using json play fromework

```
val creds:DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain
val s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(creds)
val uri: AmazonS3URI = new AmazonS3URI(conf_file)
val s3Object: S3Object = s3Client.getObject(uri.getBucket, uri.getKey)

val json = Json.parse(s3Object.getObjectContent)

val mylist = (json \ "mydata").get.as[List[JsValue]]
```

But this line gives an error

> val mylist = (json \ "mydata").get.as[List[JsValue]]

as

> no such element "mydata"

Can anyone tell how to access a json file and read its contents using json play in scala.

I am able to access same file from local machine, as well as fetch contents of "mydata" from within json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried to Print first the object and check if it is formatted properly to JSON, because everything seems works fine to me.

```
val json: JsValue = Json.parse("""{
  "mydata": [
    {"first": "aa"},
    {"second": "bb"},
    {"third": "cc"}
  ]
}""")
```

Try to implement something like this.

```
(json \ "mydata").asOpt[Seq[JsValue]].getOrElse(None)
```

Comment: If that helps you can check the solution :)

Comment: Does it work for your file on S3, bcoz it is working for me from local machine

Comment: Yeah.. Just make sure `s3Object.getObjectContent` has data from S3 with Json formatted text

Comment: Yup figured it out, I had given another filename which did not have "mydata". Anyways Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm happy to help.